# Jekyll Error: Can't find user

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I recently changed one of my post .markdown files. I don't believe I changed anything else. When running `jekyll serve`, I get this error:

```
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  can't find user $15-11-15-Post-Title.markdown
```

I don't understand whats going on. The file is there in _posts, and even if it wasn't why should it matter?

I have tried googling for this error but have found nothing. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I've got the same kind of error once, and when I checked my post I had updated the date, so the post date didn't match the file date. By correcting this, everything went back to normal...

Comment: That's not it, the dates match. And even after updating both of the dates it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Well, I just had to revert to the last commit and do the changes again. I still have no idea what happened.

Comment: I got the same error, but in my case it was because my filename started with a tilde (~myfile.html), and there was a **[bug in jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4457)**.